# How to skip Enter key in RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I have to implement transparent textbox (my case is text box with gradient background).
The easiest implementation was transparent RichTextBox which I have found on
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Regular_Expressions/Q_23508382.html

The only problem with that that I need to have single entry line, not a multyline

How to preprocess Enter key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`RichTextBox.Multiline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.multiline.aspx) to `false`.